# Should I use FB.API to store player save game information?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm prototyping a game using the FB.SDK and Unity3d (v5.0).

While working through the tutorials on Facebook about how to use the SDK I found the use of this code slightly confusing:
`FB.API("/me/scores", HttpMethod.POST, OnUserInfoSaved, scoreData);`

I am wondering why this is specifically referred to as "scores". Surely this can be any information I wish to store as part of this user's information?

In designing this game, the thought has occurred to me that I might just serialise the player's game information and send it up to Facebook using the API. Is this the intended use for that call or is there some reason to not do it that way?

Comment: Facebook will not store your save state. You will have to store that yourself

Comment: do we need to create a 'scores' object too or is that by default?

Comment: @user1683989 it's a default object on the user's profile. See the link below for more. Just as a further point to this - when I dug into this a little deeper I found a great platform called PlayFab that may be worth investigation if you're trying to do the same thing I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a bad place to save save state information. Facebook "scores" [accept a single integer value](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores), which appears publicly (if the player gave permissions) in the facebook profile, so he can compare his "score" to this friends. It wasn't intended to serve for that purpose.

Comment: Oh! I thought it was any base type not just an int. Whoops.